# Keyboard Shortcut or PowerShell Command to Open Set up Repeat and Slow Keys

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I need to open "Set up Repeat and Slow Keys" in Control Panel through command prompt/PowerShell. But I am not able to do so. Any shortcut or command would be of much help.

[Repeat Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgwAI.jpg)

I can able to open till this point,

[Filter Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysErW.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What command are you using to get that point?

Comment: @Scepticalist The  command ```control.exe /name "Microsoft.EaseOfAccessCenter" /page "pageFilterKeysSettings"``` opens "Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Set up Filter Keys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell script should work:

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

& control.exe /name "Microsoft.EaseOfAccessCenter" /page "pageFilterKeysSettings"

Do {
    Sleep 1
}
while( !(Get-Process | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq 'WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp' }) )


[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{Tab 7}')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{Enter}')
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no documented shortcut direct to that page. If you need to amend the settings, this can be done through the registry and group policy

Disable Sticky Keys

> HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys - Flags=506

Disable Filter Keys

> HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response] - Flags=122

Disable Toggle Keys

> HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys - Flags=58

Or for all NEW users:

Disable Sticky Keys

> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys - Flags=506

Disable Filter Keys

> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response -
>   Flags=122

Disable Toggle Keys

> HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys - Flags=58